# Can anyone find the Cartier designs for the unmade Baroda Crown of Maharaja Sayajirao Gaekwad III?

Tags: india, jewelry

This video, [The Great Indian Crowns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXbxZ7TnaZ0), featuring Jewellery Historian and Author Rene Brus, mentions a 'Crown Project' at the 14:23 mark. It was a 1930s project to make a crown for Maharaja [Sayajirao Gaekwad III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayajirao_Gaekwad_III#Cultural_and_material_interests) of [Baroda State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baroda_State), and it is said that the project - although never completed - did last for several years, with Cartier making a number of designs. They also provide this image with the caption that it is one of the designs for the 'Baroda Crown', although it looks like a turban headpiece so common to the era, raising the question whether he was seeking a crown or a turban with headpiece. I'm wondering if anyone can find the design images that Cartier drew up.

[image]

The project is briefly mentioned in the book [Cartier, by Hans Nadelhoffer](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=xnKpjh1gkqgC&pg=PA324&lpg=PA324&dq=baroda%20crown%20cartier&source=bl&ots=MqhJM5Wp_6&sig=ACfU3U23gWfGGsbjuW60GjfF-9QVDFfq2g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih546Z_87pAhWTxosBHVVXCA0Q6AEwCnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=baroda%20crown%20cartier&f=false), but focuses more on the 'Nassak' diamond that Jacques Cartier suggested the Prince buy for *"the central stone in the turban ornament"*. The paragraph also says the project was for a "crown and a turban," making me wonder exactly what the order was, for a crown or a turban with ornament or both.

[This article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/vadodara/barodians-should-get-chance-to-see-their-heritage/articleshow/63863315.cms) with Radhikaraje Gaekwad, a member of erstwhile Baroda royal family, mentions 14 sketches having been made by Cartier for a project that was never realized.

Comment: [This book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/0VBQAAAAMAAJ) by Judy Rudoe looks like it may have a little more info. The preview of that book is limited so I'm guessing but, there may not be any published copies of the drawings themselves. They are presumably in the [Cartier archives](https://www.cartier.com/en-us/maison/living-heritage/archives-and-expertise/archives.html).

Comment: @BrianZ Thanks a lot. I've contacted Cartier via Facebook Messenger, Mwa-hahaha! Needless to say, I'm not expecting to get anything from them. It will no doubt be a dead end, but there's no harm in trying anyway! :-)